# Loop for Agenda with day hours and fill data from DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, for-loop, while-loop

I am stuck and I guess is a loop issue, can someone help me out here and tell me what is it that I am doing wrong? This is what I have:

```
$this->time = mktime(7,0,0,$this->date);

    for($i=1;$i<56;$i++) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . date('H:i', $this->time) . '</td>';
        while($this->results = $this->sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            if (date('H:i:s', $this->time) != $this->results['time']) {
                $this->agenda = '<td>' . $this->results['name'] . '</td></tr>';
            } else {
                $this->agenda = '<td>This Hour is free</td></tr>';
            }
            echo $this->agenda;
        }

        $this->time += 900;
    }
```

What I am trying to do and get is:
Display a range of time from 7am to 8:30pm using 24 hours format, also the hours should split every 15min, that's why I incremented the for loop on 900.
on the hours that match the db, show the name of the person, other wise show This Hour is free.

But I am having trouble with the table and loop/bucle order
Thanks and appreciate it

Comment: Include what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might be of use - it uses the `DateTime`, `DateTimeZone` and `DateInterval` classes but doesn't incorporate your code to check the db results - that should be fairly straightforward.

```
<?php
    define('BR','<br />');
    $df='H:i';
    $timezone=new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
    $interval=new DateInterval('PT15M');

    $ts=date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('6.45am') );
    $tf=date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('8.30pm') );

    $start=new DateTime( $ts, $timezone );
    $end=new DateTime( $tf, $timezone );

    while( $start->add( $interval ) <= $end ){
        echo $start->format( $df ) . BR;
    }

    $timezone=$interval=$ts=$tf=$start=$end=null;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Ram, but it did not worked for me, it works as you said and a you expected, but it shows the same thing as in my loop, I get only the first result from database. What I am trying to to is to match the hour given from the for loop (ie: 07:00, 07:15, 07:30,...) with the data in my DB